# Python 2.7: user input character range checking

Tags: python-2.7, character

Not sure how to accomplish what I want:

I am first asking the user to input a letter ranging from A to H. Once I grab that input, I want do STUFF if the input was valid, but I'm not sure how to verify that the input was valid.

```py
while True: 
    input= raw_input("Enter letter between A-H: ") 
    if input "BETWEEN A-H": # (this is where I'm stuck) 
        # DO STUFF 
        break 
    else: 
        print "Invalid input. Try again" 
        continue
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the Unicode value of the character (with [`ord(character`)](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#ord)) and check if it is in the desired range.

Comment: so would... if (ord(input) in range(97,105)): ...be acceptable code?

Comment: I'd check the input to make sure it's a character before